# Authenticating user for Sharepoint Online in client/server environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, claims-based-auth

Currently, I am developing a website (for internal usage) which requires retrieving of certain data from my corporate's SharePoint page.

**Below will be the code used:**

```
    Using ctx As ClientContext = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com")

        If ctx IsNot Nothing Then

            web = ctx.Web
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web)
            ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        End If
    End Using
```

For now, I am able to authenticate users using *`ClaimsClientContext`* 
testing in my *localhost*. However after I published the website and deploy onto my server, it does not work.

Can anyone point me towards the right direction on How to authenticate users in the client/server environment?